# MySQL timestamp auto updating

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp

I have a table which contains a couple timestamp fields and but I'm having some problems having some of the fields defaulting to NULL.

In my *users* table I have these timestamp tables:

```
(field),(NULL),(default val)

deleted_on YES NULL
last_change_attemp YES NULL
newpass_time YES NULL
last_login YES NULL
created NO 0000-00-00 00:00:00
updates YES NULL
```

When I go edit a row in phpMyAdmin, the row I'm editing already has the NULL checkbox checked for all NULL fields, except the first field: *deleted_on*. If I manually check the checkbox, it allows me to maintain that field as NULL.

When I update another field via a query, it automatically does a current_timestamp on that first field.  Is this expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read through the docs again and noticed this piece of text

> To specify automatic default or updating for a TIMESTAMP column other
>   than the first one, you must suppress the automatic initialization and
>   update behaviors for the first TIMESTAMP column by explicitly
>   assigning it a constant DEFAULT value (for example, DEFAULT 0 or
>   DEFAULT '2003-01-01 00:00:00'). Then, for the other TIMESTAMP column,
>   the rules are the same as for the first TIMESTAMP column, except that
>   if you omit both of the DEFAULT and ON UPDATE clauses, no automatic
>   initialization or updating occurs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

So for the time being I have the fields default to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to prevent auto updates.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin does some weird things with timestamps and null, especially if the column is marked as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I don't know why.